# How to make evil keymaps inherit from other evil keymaps?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, evil

I changed the <kbd>i</kbd> key binding in `evil-normal-state-map` to go up and <kbd>k</kbd> to go down (these are just two examples). But `evil-operator-state-map` and `evil-visual-state-map` do not change accordingly, but keep the old key bindings (i.e. `hijk`). Even making new keymap and assign key bindings, it still uses the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These maps inherit from motion state: if keys are not bound in the other states, they will take their bindings from above.  So:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "i" #'evil-previous-line)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "k" #'evil-next-line)
```

Now, provided that the other maps do not already have bindings for `i` and `k`, they will use the ones you defined in `evil-motion-state-map`.